# Git hook to increment version number on merge to master

Tags: git, npm, githooks

The goal is to automatically increment the version number in `package.json` when the `develop` branch is merged to `master`, but not what a feature branch is merged to `develop`, nor when then `release` branch is merged to `master`. (I'm oversimplifying my usecase a bit, but that's basically it.)

Actually incrementing the version number is easy - there's already an npm command to do that.

But I don't understand how to write the Git hook to run that command. How do I determine the name of the current branch, and the branch being merged into? Can this be done in a pre-merge-commit hook? Is it even possible to edit the source and make a commit *from* the pre-merge-commit hook?

Comment: Don't store the version number in a file in the repo.  Instead, derive the version number from git.

Comment: I would use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@corteks/gitversion in my CI chain to automatically set the version using git tags instead of trying to manage it manually.

Comment: That's not the goal. The npm project already has a semantic version number. The goal is to auto-increment it, not randomize it, not infer it from tags.

Comment: Way off to the side note, but it sounds like you are possibly close to a Git Flow strategy, and if so, you could just stop merging `develop` into `master` and then you won't ever have to increment the version for merges into `master`. Instead, always make a `release` branch in between and do it there, which I'm guessing you already do, sometimes.

Comment: @TTT My team does something (kindof?) similar to Git Flow, but we merge develop into master, and then do any necessary hotfixes on the release branches which are branched *off of* master. Idk what this strategy is called. Apologies if I'm using standard naming conventions in nonstandard ways.

Comment: @MathewAlden OK. Yeah- those are unconventional branch names. No worries; branch names don't really matter as long as your team is clear on what they are.

Comment: The nice thing about git is that it is super-simple to test these things locally. You don't need a fancy server, just make a bare repo, clone it, and start pushing various different changes and see what hooks get triggered with what parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest have a CI job called `release`, with release version as a parameter (you may further automate to let it auto-increment if wanted).

When `release` job is triggered, it will have a new commit to master changing the version to the specified release version, tagging it with git, then publish the incremented version directly.

Doing that will make sure the published version, and tagged version is the correct version, and reduce the number of auto commits with the hook every time committed to master.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But why do it as a CI job rather than a Git hook? Is it not possible to do as a Git hook?

Comment: It is doable with Git hook, but it will generate lots of auto commits every time you committed to master.

With a release job, if you want, you may auto trigger it every time you merge to master, or with specific condition that you want to trigger it after merging. So it should be more flexible than Git hooks.

Comment: One more downside with Git hook, it is a local developer config and client side.

To share the hook, you would need to save the hook file in other location to workaround to commit that to the repo. Then copy and pasting back to the local config.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I've edited my question to clarify why I'm not sure a CI job is right for my usecase. That is, I want this npm command to run conditionally when some branches are merged to master but not when other branches are merged to master, based on the name of the branch.